# Uniform Convergence of a Sequence of Summations

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

**Given:**

$f_1(x)=x$ if $x\le1/2$

$f_1(x)=1-x$ if $1/2\le x\le1$

$f_1(x+1)=f_1(x)$

$\forall n\ge2,f_n(x)=(1/2)*f_{n-1}(2x)$

Let $S_m(x)=\sum_{n=1}^m f_n(x)$

$S_m$ is a continuous function on $[0,\infty]$

**Task:**

Show that the sequence $(S_m)_{m \epsilonℕ}$ converges uniformly to a continuous function S.

**My question:**

I'm sorry, I don't really have one. I'm just totally clueless. I know I'm supposed to show the work that I've done up to this point, but I do not know how to work with uniform convergence. We were introduced to it it a few months ago, but it didn't make sense to me then, and it doesn't make sense to me now.

Here's my given definition for uniform convergence: Let $(f_n)_{n\epsilonℕ}$ be a sequence of functions in the real numbers. The sequence is said to converge uniformly to a function $f$ provided that, given $\epsilon\gt0$, there exists $N_\epsilon \in ℕ$ such that $sup_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\lt\epsilon$ for $n\ge N_\epsilon$

Comment: Do you understand regular convergence first?

Comment: As in pointwise? I understand pointwise convergence better than I do uniform, largely because I have had a very difficult time really processing the difference. I've read that the difference is that uniform convergence depends only on epsilon, while pointwise convergence depends on epsilon and x. This difference makes sense when I read it but I have had trouble applying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the relation $f_n(x)=2^{-1}f_{n-1}(2x)$ implies that for every $n$, $f_n(x)=2^{1-n}f_1(2^{n-1}x)$. Now, note that for every real $x$, we have $\vert f_1(x)\vert \leq 1$. Hence, we obtain the relation $0\leq f_n(x)\leq 2^{1-n}$ for every $x$ (the first inequality follows by the definition of $f_n$).
We can apply then the Weierstrass M-test to show that the sequence of functions $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$. Since all the $S_n$ are continuous the limit function (say $S$) is continuous.

Edit:
A proof that doesn't use explicitly the M-test is as follows:
We know that the limit function exist for every $x$. Now, note that
$$
\vert S_n(x)-S(x)\vert=\sum_{m=n}^\infty f_m(x)\leq \sum_{m=n}^\infty 2^{1-m}= 2^{2-n}
$$
Since this is valid for every $x$, then we must have that $\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\vert S_n(x)-S(x)\vert\leq 2^{2-n}$
Then, the supremun can be made as small as desired taking $n$ large enough. This implies that the convergence is uniform

Comment: Wow, thanks. Unfortunately, I can't find in my book the Weierstrass M-test nor the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence which Rudin (an author I'm using as a supplemental source) uses to prove the Weierstrass test. Is there another similarly straightforward way to approach this problem? If not, I can just use Rudin to rewrite the proof for the Weierstrass test.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check if that approach suits you, please